# setMovementMethod doesn't work in android textview

Tags: java, android, html, string, android-xml

I have a textview whose text is coming from database. This text can be normal text or it can be a link or both. For this, I am parsing text in html using `Html.fromHtml(myText)`. So that link can be detected and display as clickable. This is working fine. It displays clickable string for links and non-clickable for normal text. But when I click that text, it doesn't work and nothing happens. **This is what I am getting from server as text :**

```
Dear user:

Your review titled <a href="http://example.com/review/someText-1069459" target="blank">Normal verified negative 1 desktop</a> on the product <a href="http://example.com/product-reviews/text-925766045"  target="blank">Clickable Text</a> has been resolved.

To check corporate response  <a target="blank" href="http://example.com/interact.php?add=http://example.com/blog/ejhhspsqmn/Please-talk-about-your-companys-products-and-services-onlyPlease-present-your-post-in-an-objectiv&session_id=Se9qExA6JSY%3d">Click here</a>

Have a great day! 

Regards,
Head - Member Support
```

**To make clickable text, I use setMovementMethod like below :**

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(myText));
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

But its not working. Is there anything that I am missing to add in code ? Also I am using  `android:autoLink="web"` in xml.

[image]

Comment: your code is working fine,nothing problem to open browser

Comment: No its not working. @AbhishekPatel

Comment: I try with your data as a string and add one `Textview` and click on link open  it in browser

Comment: @AbhishekPatel I am using listView and inside listview, I have textview for each row in which I am using setMovementMethod. Is this listview can be problem for not working of this method ?

Comment: no i already try with listview please show your question I Update that(Image upload)

Answer (score 4):

Remove the android:autoLink="web" in xml.

Answer (score 2):

You can either user LinkMoveMethod interface or Linkify

Example :----

```
TextViewObject.setText(Html.fromHtml("YOur Text "));
TextViewObj.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

OR

```
Linkify.addLinks(new SpannableString(Html.fromHtml("Your Text"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding these attributes to textview in xml worked for me

`android:focusable="true"`
 `android:scrollbars="vertical"`

then in Kotlin

`textview.movementMethod = ScrollingMovementMethod()`