# Trouble with setting up a link to a textview that will open up a site

Tags: android

I've seen few questions like this but I'm a beginner and cannot quite fix this while looking at other people's different problems. So, my problem is pretty simple actually, I just have a TextView in my RecyclerView, and whenever I want to press that Highlighted TextView I want it to open up a site that I direct it to, I guess something's missing in my MainActivity, but not sure what. Here's my xml code :

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/shoptext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="60dp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:linksClickable="true"
            android:autoLink="web"
            android:textColorLink="@color/black"
            android:text="@string/shop"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/myText2" />
```

Here's my MainActivity code :

```
 shopText = findViewById(R.id.shoptext);
 shopText.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [setMovementMethod doesn't work in android textview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37429656/setmovementmethod-doesnt-work-in-android-textview)

Answer (score 0):

try this may helps

```
       TextView link = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view_id);
        String linkText =  getString(R.string.acceop)
               +  "<a href='https://www.dmaghi.com/eula/terms/terms.html'> " + getString(R.string.trms) + " </a>"
               +  getString(R.string.acceop2)
               +  "<a href='https://www.dmaghi.com/eula/policies/privacy/privacy.html'> " + getString(R.string.polces) + " </a>.";
        link.setText(Html.fromHtml(linkText));
        link.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```